# Is there a way to convert from a component with inputs to raw html?

Tags: html, vue.js, components

I have a component in Vue component-z.

I need to pass in certain parameters, so when I use this in my Vue's html I do as follows:

```
<component-z id="component" data1="data" data2="moreData"></component-z>
```

I need to take the html out of this and pass it as a message to a parent frame (from an iFrame). Is there a way to do something like:

```
<component-z id="component" data1="data" data2="moreData"></component-z>.toHtml()
```

Comment: Perhaps use something like `document.getElementById('component').innerHTML`

Comment: In this case I do not actually have an instance of the component, just the definition of the template and parameters to pass in

Answer (score 0):

First, add a `ref` attribute to the line, such as `ref='component-z'`

If you are inside the `<script>` portion of the Vue file, you can access the Vue instance and its references like this:

```
this.$refs
```

To access the outer HTML (or rendered/raw HTML) of that component, use

```
this.$refs["component-z"].$el.outerHTML
```

Note the "component-z" portion of that JavaScript, which corresponds to that `ref` attribute you set.

Comment: Naming a `ref` with hyphen-case will return an error. To access the ref the right way, you have to write `this.$refs['component-z']`

Comment: @JimmerFlash Not sure what you mean. Try the solution out and let me know what happens.